# Getting a a syntax error, all code provided

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm somewhat new to php and MySQL.  I'm going through a tutorial and get the error message below when click the edit subject button.  I'll include all the applicable code i'm working with.  I'm fairly certain the problem lies with the database connection as the error being displayed is printed from the connection.php page.

Error:

> Database connection failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Databases:

```
   I have 1 database(widget_corp) with 3 tables 
   Tables:
   subjects(id, menu_name, position, visible), 
   pages(id, subject_id, menu_name, position, visible, content), 
   users(id, username, hashed_password) //this one is not used yet
```

Source Code:

```
    <?PHP require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
    <?PHP require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
    <?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $errors = array();
    $required_fields = array('menu_name', 'position', 'visible');
    foreach($required_fields as $fieldname) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || (empty($_POST[$fieldname]) && !is_numeric($_POST[$fieldname]))) {
    $errors[] = $fieldname;
    }
    }
    $fields_with_lengths = array('menu_name' => 30);
    foreach($fields_with_lengths as $fieldname => $maxlength) {
    if(strlen(trim(mysql_prep($_POST[$fieldname]))) > $maxlength) {
    $errors[] = $fieldname; }
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
    // Perform Update
    $id = mysql_prep($_GET['subj']);
    $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST['menu_name']);
    $position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
    $visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

    $query = "UPDATE subjects SET menu_name = '{$menu_name}',  position = {$position}, visible = {$visible} WHERE id = {$id}";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
    // Sucess
    } else {
    // Failed
    }
    } else {
    } // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    }
    ?>
    <?PHP find_selected_page(); ?>

    <?PHP include("includes/header.php"); ?>

    <table id="structure">
    <tr>
    <td id="navigation">
    <?PHP echo navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page); ?>
    </td>
    <td id="page">
    <h2>Edit Subject: <?PHP echo $sel_subject['menu_name']; ?></h2>           
    <form action="edit_subject.php?subj="<?PHP echo urlencode($sel_subject['id']); ?>" method="post">
    <p>Subject name:
    <input type="text" name="menu_name" value="<?PHP echo $sel_subject['menu_name']; ?>" id="menu_name" />
    </p>
    <p>Position:
    <select name="position">
    <?PHP
    $subject_set = get_all_subjects();
    $subject_count = mysql_num_rows($subject_set);
    // $subject_count +1 b/c we are adding a subject
    for($count=1; $count <= $subject_count+1; $count++) {
    echo "<option value=\"{$count}\"";
    if ($sel_subject['position'] == $count) {
    echo " selected";
    }
    echo ">{$count}</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>Visible:
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0"<?PHP
    if($sel_subject['visible'] == 0) { echo " checked"; }
    ?>/> No
    &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" <?PHP
    if($sel_subject['visible'] ==1) {echo " checked"; }
    ?>  /> Yes
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit Subject" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <a href="content.php">Cancel</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?PHP require("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Applicable functions from functions.php

```
    function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
    header("Location: {$location}");
    exit;
    }
    }

    function navigation($sel_subject, $sel_page) {
    $output =  "<ul class=\"subjects\" >";
    $subject_set = get_all_subjects();
    while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
    $output .= "<li";
    if ($subject["id"] == $sel_subject["id"]) {$output .= " class=\"selected\"";}
    $output .= "><a href=\"edit_subject.php?subj=" . urlencode($subject["id"]) . "\">{$subject["menu_name"]}</a></li>";

    $page_set = get_pages_for_subject($subject["id"]);  
    $output .= "<ul class=\"pages\">";
    while ($page = mysql_fetch_array($page_set)) {
    $output .= "<li";
    if ($page['id']==$sel_page['id']) {$output .= " class=\"selected\"";}
    $output .= "><a href=\"content.php?page=" . urlencode($page["id"]) . "\">{$page["menu_name"]}</a></li>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
    return $output;
    }

    function mysql_prep($value) {
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
    if ($new_enough_php) { //PHP v4.3.0 or higher
    // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
    if($magic_quotes_active) { $value = stripslashes($value); }
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else { //before PHP v4.3.0
    // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slahses manually
    if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes($value); }
    // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
    }

    function get_subject_by_id($subject_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE `id`= ' . (int)$subject_id . 'LIMIT 1';
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    // REMEMBER:
    //if no rowes are returned, fetch array will return false
    if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    return $subject;
    } else { 
    return NULL;
    }
    }

    function get_pages_for_subject($subject_id) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "Select * 
    FROM pages 
    WHERE subject_id={$subject_id} 
    ORDER BY position ASC";

    $pages_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($pages_set);
    return $pages_set;
    }

    function get_page_by_id($page_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `id` = ' . (int)$page_id . ' LIMIT 1';
    $result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($result_set);
    // REMEMBER:
    //if no rowes are returned, fetch array will return false
    if ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    return $subject;
    } else { 
    return NULL;
    }
    }

    function get_all_subjects() {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY position ASC";
    $subject_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($subject_set);    
    return $subject_set;                
    }

    function find_selected_page() {
    global $sel_subject;
    global $sel_page;

    if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {
    $sel_subject  = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
    $sel_page = NULL;
    } else if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $sel_subject = NULL;
    $sel_page = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
    } else{
    $sel_subject = NULL;
    $sel_page = NULL;
    }   
    }

    function confirm_query($result_set) {
    if (!$result_set) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    }
```

Included pages

```
    header.php

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Widget Corp</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/public.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Widget Corp</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main"></div></body></html>
```

footer.php

```
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright 2007, Widget Corp</div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?PHP
    if (isset($connection)){
    mysql_close($connection);
    }
    ?>
```

connection.php

```
    <?PHP
    require("constants.php");
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
    if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    ?>
```

constants.php

```
    <?PHP   
    // Database Constants
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "root");
    define("DB_PASS", "********");
    define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp");
    ?>
```

Comment: We only need the SQL query, not your entire code.

Comment: Are we supposed to do your job?

Comment: @Jason That's in the code, not an error from MySQL.

Comment: Also remove the closing `</body></html>` from `header.php`, or you will close twice (once in header, once in footer)

Comment: @slash28cu  I've spent several hours trying to figure this out.  I'm just trying to get answers.

Comment: @deceze  Sorry, i've tried posting a similar question with not enough information and it was closed. i guess i'm giving too much this time lol.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the first PHP line and debug it!!!!!

Comment: @Mike Try to learn to judge what is relevant to a problem and what is not. That typically already brings you 90% of the way to the solution...

Comment: @MikeJohnson: Yes, this time, too much. Well not too much, just the wrong code. Locate where the error occurs, debug there.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that in functions.php, you have the line

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `subjects` WHERE `id`= ' . (int)$subject_id . 'LIMIT 1';
```

and there is no space before `LIMIT`. Try changing `'LIMIT 1'` to `' LIMIT 1'` and see what happens.

To spot these errors more quickly, you need to add just some little lines of error-checking:

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
if (!$result_set) {
    echo "mysql_query() error: ", mysql_error($connection), "\nquery was: $query\n";
    die();
}
```

You will then see as well the SQL you have generated which allows to spot the error quickly.

Comment: I could have sworn I had made that change several times. That has fixed the actual error.  Thanks.

Comment: @hakre Just curious to know why you edited my answer rather than adding a comment, as now my answer is actually more your answer. Your edit is helpful, but just wondering why you added that helpful information to my answer.

Comment: @jdwire: Just to make the answer more complete and to add some value to it. It still is your answer btw., however please read this for some details: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: @haker I've read that FAQ. I'm fine with your edit. I just thought it was interesting that you edited it that much as most edits I've seen have only been to fix grammar or correct errors rather than add information.

Comment: Well, there is no limit to the extend of an edit. Just see it as some addition to your answer and maybe next time you place an answer, give some good tips, too. Because you don't want the have a user ask next time again only because for example the space is missing after `LIMIT` or something comparable ;)